# When last string removed it causes app to crash

Tags: java, android, string, arraylist

Ok.. Here is my problem.
I have an arraylist of stings with 10 items in it.
Then I randomize the list and display a random string in a textview.
With the last string removed the app crashes. Any tip to fix that?
Here is the code:

```
    Collections.shuffle(learnlist);
    showlearntv.setText(learnlist.get(0));
    nextlearn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            showlearntv.setText(learnlist.get(1));
            learnlist.remove(0);
```

Comment: Don't call `learnlist.get(1)` before making sure `learnlist.size()>1`.

Comment: do not remove/get if there is no items

Comment: Can I somehow make a text that says "end of list" for final string?

Comment: you must be getting exceptions right?

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting to call `get(1)` on a list that may contain less than two elements.
You should add some safety checks. E.g.:

```
nextlearn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (!learnlist.isEmpty()) {
            learnlist.remove(0);
        }
        if (!learnlist.isEmpty()) {
            showlearntv.setText(learnlist.get(0));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

On the click handler, remove the item first,

```
learnlist.remove(0)
```

Then if the list has any items,

```
showlearntv.setText(learnlist.get(0));
```

Else do something else.